# open webim ( Mibew Messenger ) time out, reconnecting

Tags: php, timeout

i hope you guys know about [webim](http://mibew.org/) a.k.a mibew messenger. I know only java, jsp and no idea about php except for some basics. Anyways, i ran this app in my apache2.2 local server. Everything works superb! But if i change my db to a virtual machine and give its address in the config.php (previously i had used localhost), in the visitors page, i get timeout, reconnecting. Login has no prob, so my guess is db connection is fine. I even changed the default page refresh time from 2 to 10. Nothing happens. Still same thing. You guys have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In users.php, you may get "time out, reconnecting" if the number of in chat sessions is so great that it takes too long for the javascript to retrieve and update the page.

select istate,count(*) from chatthread group by istate;

Look at the number of chat threads with a status = 2.

If it's big (mine was over 1000), then you can update the chatthread table.

update chatthread set istate=3 where istate=2 and dtmcreated < date(now()-interval 1 day) ;

Above query updates threads older than yesterday where the consumer simply closed their window and went away.

Why does this happen? In my case, it's because customer service department did not log into midew for over a week and there were too many messages threads for the users.php/javascript to retrieve and display.

Answer (score 0):

Replace users.php with update.php in the address bar. Load it. There should be valid xml code. You'll see if there are any errors.